# ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, npm

I have a existing project and I am trying to make it run, but i am facing lots of issue.
while installing I am getting this error "ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree"

[image]

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-native-starter@2.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react-native@0.59.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   react-native@"0.59.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native@"^0.41.2" from react-native-android-installed-apps@1.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-android-installed-apps
npm ERR!   react-native-android-installed-apps@"^1.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/user/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2021-05-14T11_31_41_074Z-debug.log
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-native-starter",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:update": "jest -u",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "run:ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "run:android": "react-native run-android",
    "lint": "./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js src",
    "lint:fix": "./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js src --fix",
    "flow": "./node_modules/flow-bin/cli.js",
    "e2e:build": "detox build --configuration ios.sim.debug",
    "e2e:test": "detox test --configuration ios.sim.debug"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@exponent/react-native-action-sheet": "^0.3.0",
    "@jumpn/react-native-jetifier": "^0.1.4",
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.1.2",
    "dev": "^0.1.3",
    "i18n-js": "^3.2.1",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "lottie-react-native": "^3.3.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-keyboard-event-handler": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native": "0.59.1",
    "react-native-android-installed-apps": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-contacts": "3.1.5",
    "react-native-countdown-circle": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^3.1.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.10.3",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.6",
    "react-native-flexi-radio-button": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.0.16",
    "react-native-get-sms-android": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "1.x.x",
    "react-native-image-view": "^2.1.9",
    "react-native-indicator": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-lightbox": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.3",
    "react-native-localize": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.27.1",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.16.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.6.2",
    "react-native-nav": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.18.3",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-razorpay": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-select-contact-fix": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-share": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-sim-data": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-sms": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-step-indicator": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.13.6",
    "react-native-svg-img": "^2.0.6",
    "react-native-swiper-flatlist": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-switch-selector": "^2.0.6",
    "react-native-ui-lib": "^3.18.0",
    "react-native-ui-xg": "^0.0.6",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^7.4.3",
    "react-navigation": "^3.3.2",
    "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^2.1.2",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^1.0.0",
    "react-navigation-transitions": "^1.0.12",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-promise": "^0.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-tri-toggle-switch": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^24.5.0",
    "danger": "^7.0.2",
    "detox": "^9.1.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.7.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.0",
    "eslint": "^5.9.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "flow-bin": "0.92.0",
    "jest": "^24.5.0",
    "jsdom": "13.0.0",
    "jsdom-global": "3.0.2",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "plop": "^2.2.0",
    "prettier": "^1.16.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3",
    "sinon": "^7.1.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!**/node_modules/**",
      "!android/**",
      "!ios/**",
      "!assets/**"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "jest_coverage",
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jest-setup.js"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/",
      "/e2e/"
    ]
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  },
  "detox": {
    "configurations": {
      "ios.sim.debug": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeStarter.app",
        "build": "xcodebuild -UseModernBuildSystem=NO -project ios/ReactNativeStarter.xcodeproj -scheme ReactNativeStarter -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone XS"
      },
      "ios.sim.release": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeStarter.app",
        "build": "xcodebuild -UseModernBuildSystem=NO -project ios/ReactNativeStarter.xcodeproj -scheme ReactNativeStarter -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone 7"
      }
    },
    "test-runner": "jest"
  }
}
```

PS: I don't know anything about react native so kindly give the answers accordingly.If you need something let me know

I already have deleted node_modules and package_json_lock

Comment: Upgrading to 'react-native' version 0.64.1 solved the problem for me.

Comment: @Rohit I am getting error after running `npx react-native upgrade` 
 fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Answer (score 2):

May be downgrading to v12.16.1 will work
& running

```
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try npm install node or, if that too dosen't work, you can use yarn install. If you use yarn install, use the yarn specific codes in future commands (which do not have much difference compared to npm)

Answer (score 0):

the node version in your system is higher compare to the setting in project dependencies (package.json). Try to use node version manager(nvm) so you can have multiple node version, then install the node version lower than the current version.
Can check here how to install nvm:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-version-manager-nvm-install-guide/