# Vue 2 build error - ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: node.js, vuejs2, eslint, npm-install

I'm getting the following dependency issues centering around `eslint` when I try to build my Vue 2 app.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: vue-crm@2.2.3
npm ERR! Found: eslint@8.16.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   dev eslint@">=7.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@"^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/parser@2.34.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser
npm ERR!   dev @typescript-eslint/parser@"^2.26.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @typescript-eslint/parser@"^2.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.34.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!     dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^2.26.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

I have tried changing the `eslint` version in the `package.json` to several different versions but nothing resolves the issue.

I have also tried running `npm install --save  --legacy-peer-deps` as suggested for [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67533752/eresolve-unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree) and, though the build begins, it hangs shortly after at about half way through like so:

`########⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⸩ ⠋ idealTree: timing idealTree Completed in 29424ms`

I am particularly confused by the line `npm ERR! Found: eslint@8.16.0`. I don't know where this is being found and the version number that it complains about might change each time I try another one in the `package.json`.

I've been trying to fix this for a couple of days now without any luck. If anyone can tell me what is needed to resolve it I would be very grateful.

Comment: When you say you've "changed the `eslint` version in the package.json to several different versions [to no avail]", you reinstalled packages (or just eslint specifically) each time you updated the version number in package.json right? Another thought: do you have a global install of eslint that could be interfering maybe? (`npm list -g --depth=0`)